# getting error while connecting to mongo.exe

Tags: mongodb

While trying to open connection,I am getting following error in mongo db.

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin>mongo.exe
MongoDB shell version v3.6.4
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2018-05-13T21:36:21.154+0530 I NETWORK  [thread1] Socket recv() An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine. 127.0.0.1:27017
2018-05-13T21:36:21.156+0530 I NETWORK  [thread1] SocketException: remote: (NONE):0 error: SocketException socket exception [RECV_ERROR] server [127.0.0.1:27017]
2018-05-13T21:36:21.157+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: network error while attempting to run command 'isMaster' on host '127.0.0.1:27017'  :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:251:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

Comment: are you sure that the mongo server is running ? use the command `mongod` to run it from the terminal

Comment: which OS you are using???

Comment: I am using windows and yes mongod is running.